# What is the proper grammatical use of domain name in a web site?

Tags: seo

I have a non-technical issue, in fact it is probably more grammatical in nature.  On http://www.FindGamers.us I tend to run the two words `find` and `gamers` together as one word in sentences because it's the domain name.  So I might say something like, "FindGamers like all web sites...."

I do it that way because it's proper noun but I'm not entirely sure its the right thing to do.  Should I say `Find Gamers` instead of `FindGamers` in page text & articles unless I am specifying the domain name?  You see, this also affects SEO.  Because I want people searching google for those words to find the site.  People don't search for the two words rammed together when they want to `find gamers` on google etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you already know the answer.

I always say write naturally first, then SEO second. It sounds like you are keeping SEO in mind more than you should. For example, when you want to refer to the domain name, then use the domain name. If you want to say find gamer(s) then say that. Do not confuse the two for the sake of SEO. Write naturally *then* tune your work.

Here is the good news. Google can find key words in just about anything. But they want natural occurrences before they put too much weight on keywords found in domain names and other somewhat questionable uses. Otherwise, the whole domain name is the keyword. That is, if I have the domain name ChocolateCookies.com (my apologies if this is a real domain name), it will perform well for ChocolateCookies.com and somewhat for Chocolate Cookies because Google makes an unsupported assumption. But if my content supports ChocolateCookies.com with the terms Chocolate Cookies though out the content, links, images, and so forth, then the site will perform better (all round) because Google no longer has to make any assumptions about what keywords are appropriate.

So in your case, use the domain name and the words in context within content how they should naturally be written. Look to see if one or the other dominates the landscape too much and try and strike a health balance.